# Android error in MainActivity?

Tags: android, fatal-error

Getting Android FATAL EXCEPTION Main error in this following code don't know why it is happening..?? Some one plz figure out for it me and plz plz help me on **finding errors myself**...!!

Main activity class :-

```
package www.gurjit.taskmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button add_button;
    private View tasklist_view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpElements(); // for setting up all the views/elements of the android page.
    }

    private void setUpElements() {
        add_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        tasklist_view = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        add_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, addActivityTask.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is my Android_Main layout file & Don't know about how this error can be occurred
although follow in the same way and used (Google API 4.3) Api level:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tasks"
        android:textColor="#12ade4"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#12ade4"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1" />

    <button
        android:id="@id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_button"
        android:textSize="15sp" 
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the logcat file appearing :-

```
01-28 09:12:45.150: D/AndroidRuntime(1766): Shutting down VM
01-28 09:12:45.150: W/dalvikvm(1766): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{www.gurjit.taskmanager/www.gurjit.taskmanager.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class button
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class button
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at www.gurjit.taskmanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     ... 11 more
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.button" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/www.gurjit.taskmanager-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/www.gurjit.taskmanager-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
01-28 09:12:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1766):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: Please paste the logcat.

Comment: it should be `<Button` with capital b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems:

1. In the java code, You forgot to cast your TextView:

   tasklist_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
2. In the XML, change `<button>` to `<Button>`
3. In the ID attribute, you forgot to put a plus before assigning the Id.:

   android:id="@+id/addButton"
4. In `RelativeLayout`s, you can not use a view for relative positioning without declaring it, so change your xml to this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/tasks"
    android:textColor="#12ade4"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add_button"
    android:textSize="15sp" 
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Comment: Also follow Piyush Gupta's note about changing `View` to `TextView` in the Java code.

Comment: Thanks W.K.S ,,i got the answer its problem of <button> in the xml..!!